# stristr with a $

Tags: php

I am not able to get a *stristr* function to come back true, and I believe it is because of a $ character in my search.

When I do:
    `var_dump($nopricecart);`

Where the full $nopricecart value is `<span class="pricedisplay">$0</span>`, I get:

> string(41) "$0"

But when I do:

```
if(stristr($nopricecart , "$0")){
   echo "*";
   } else { 
   echo $nopricecart;
}
```

I always get the variable of $nopricecart, even when it is $0.

Removing the $ from my if function works perfectly, but this is not going to work for my code.

Comment: '' == false. '' !== false. Use strict comparison. stristr($nopricecart , "$0") !== ''

Comment: `>` is not a strict comparison. it's just an inequality test.

Comment: Your code seems to work just fine: http://codepad.org/7q5sLsnV

Comment: By the way, I assume you would have the real price stored somewhere as well as an integer or something, so I would just check for that instead of using the html.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `string(41)` should give it away: It appears there are a LOT of non-printable characters in your string. Find out where they are coming from and remove them, and your code should work.

Comment: Note: you can usually use [`urlencode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) to spot these.

Comment: This is correct, and those other characters come from the core function that I get the $nopricecart from.  The full variable is <span class="pricedisplay">$0</span>

Comment: Okay, I've just reminded myself of the order of arguments: it should work. I tested it myself, and it does work on my end. Are you sure you're using `$ (U+0024 Dollar Sign)` and not `＄ (U+FF04 Fullwidth Dollar Sign)`?

Comment: The string you have given is only 36 characters long, not 41. If that dollar sign is in fact the Fullwidth one, then it would be `&#xff04;`, which would make the subject string longer... Try `echo htmlspecialchars($nopricecart)` to see what you actually have.

Comment: htmlspecialcharts = <span class='pricedisplay'>&#036;0</span>

Comment: This seems to work:  if(stristr($nopricecart , '&#036;0')){ so I might just let that ride unless you guys see any issues?

Comment: And there you go. The dollar sign isn't a dollar sign, it's an HTML character code for a dollar sign (one of several). This is why you should use an HTML parser to parse HTML ;)

Comment: @user1532904 whilst that will work, it's not advised. When dealing with HTML it should be decoded. Try sticking your $nopricecart through html_entity_decode();